# Xamarin GPS Background Service

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, location, maps

I am trying to create a Background Service in Xamarin Android and iOS that fetches the GPS location each 30-60 second. The service should work whenever the app is inactive/minimized and as well start up after a reboot (is that even possible?).

I wonder if somebody has managed to do this already and could point me to some example code? I also wonder if such a service would be disastrous for the battery consumption.